# Interpolate between two modelview matrices

Tags: opengl, rotation, translation, model-view, linear-interpolation

In OpenGL, given two camera positions (i.e. model view matrices), I would like to smoothly transition between them. That is, I want to interpolate between the two modelview matrices. I've seen many resources that talk about using SLERP to interpolate between two rotation matrices, but with camera positions we also have a translation component. **Is doing this as simple as using SLERP for the 3x3 rotation matrix and using LERP for the 3x1 translation component of the model view matrix?** My gut feeling tells me that it may not be this simple because the 3x1 translation component is not the camera's world space position, right?

If I had the actual world position for each camera position, I suppose I could break these steps into two OpenGL commands:

```
glMultMatrix(newRotation); // rotation using SLERP
glMultMatrix(newTranslation); // translation using LERP
```

If I understand it correctly, here, newTranslation is not the same as the 3x1 translation component of the model view matrix, but is the world space position of the camera.

Comment: possible duplicate of [interpolate between rotation matrices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099369/interpolate-between-rotation-matrices)

Comment: [interpolate between rotation matrices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099369/interpolate-between-rotation-matrices) is about rotation only, but the top answer mentions about doing linear interpolation for the non-rotation parts. I guess I could find the translation by multiplying the 3x1 translation component by the transpose of the 3x3 rotation component and then do linear interpolation on that...

Answer (score 2):

Why not interpolating between camera position/targets?

```
startPos = x
endPos = y
startTarget = xx
endTarget = yy
```

and in the `update()`

```
currentPos = interpolate(startPos, endPos, time_param);
currentTarget = interpolate(startTarget, endTarget, time_param);

camera_matrix = lookAt(currentPos, targetPos, upVector);
```

I think that in this way it is simpler to control camera movement.

Here are more advanced interpolation methods: http://sol.gfxile.net/interpolation/

Comment: That sounds pretty good. However, I only have the start and end model view matrices, so I suppose I could extract the position by multiplying the 3x1 translation component by the transpose of the 3x3 rotation component. Then based on the positions and the [3rd column](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html#matrix) of the model view matrices, I could create the target start and end positions. But then I'd have to use SLERP for interpolating _both_ the target positions and the up vector...right?

Comment: for vectors you can use 'normal' interpolation. Linear for start will be enough. Here are more advanced interpolation methods: http://sol.gfxile.net/interpolation/

Answer (score 0):

Linear transform is correct for the '3x1' part, to figure out why, lets dive into the Matrix transform function.

---

Say we have the model view matrix:

```
{ a, b, c, 
  d, e, f,
  g, h, i,
  x, y, z }

Where a->i is our 3x3 rotation/scale component
and x->z is the "3x1" part you were talking about.
```

And lets work with the vertex position: `{ A, B, C }`

One thing to note about these matrices/vectors is that they are actually shorthand for a '4x4' and '4x1' matrix where we substitute in the "identity" values for the missing parts of the 4x4, and '1' for the last value of the 4x1.

This means that our actual working values are:

```
{ a, b, c, 0, 
  d, e, f, 0,
  g, h, i, 0,
  x, y, z, 1 }

and
{ A, B, C, 1 }
```

Now that we've got nice, matching matrix dimensions, we can apply our `4x4 * 4x1` matrix multiply operation, which will give us a `4x1` result.

(If you don't know how to do this, go search on google, there's a heap of descent resources and it's rather simple to do)

This gives us the result:

```
{
    A*a + B*d + C*g + 1*x,
    A*b + B*e + C*h + 1*y,
    A*c + B*f + C*i + 1*z,
    A*0 + B*0 + C*0 + 1*1,
}
or (simplified):
{
    A*a + B*d + C*g + x,
    A*b + B*e + C*h + y,
    A*c + B*f + C*i + z,
    1,
}
```

Notice each component simply has `x`, `y` or `z` added to it and those values aren't used in any other way.

Nothing special is done to the '3x1' values of the matrix, it simply adds them as a position offset, therefore, doing a linear interpolation of them will result in a linear positional movement of the "camera".