# How can I smooth a sequence of affine transforms?

Tags: opencv, math, image-processing, affinetransform, homography

I've tracked a plane through an image sequence using OpenCV and produced a chain of 3x3 TRS homogenous transform matrices (actually affine/homographies, but I'm simplifying).  I now want to smooth the motion over time to stabilize the movement of the plane.  I don't want to just smooth out translation, I also want to smooth away jerks in rotation and scale.  My problem comes up when dealing with pivots.

My first thought was to decompose each matrix into T, R, S (translation/rotation/scale) components and then filter each component with Gaussian convolution.   I don't think this will work.  The problem is that if you have a pure rotational movement about a pivot that does not lie at the origin, then when decomposed as TRS both translation and rotation will need to vary in-synch over time.  If I then smooth T and R separately, odd things could happen because in this case the translation is not real translation, but translation induced by the pivot.  For example, imagine the case where I want to smooth T very little and smooth rotation a lot - this will cause wobble because the linked variation of T and R together is responsible for the rotation about the pivot.  In this particular example, if I instead decomposed as SRT rather than TRS then there would be no problem.

My second thought was that I could somehow figure out the pivots afterwards by looking at the sequence of transforms.  I could assume the existence of pivots for rotation/scale that are constant over the entire image sequence and then try to minimize (via gradient descent) the variation in the leftover translation component over the entire sequence.  I'm not sure this will work.

In general, I'm not sure this is even a solvable problem.

Comment: Have you tried with a Kalman filter?

Comment: @Steve do you find any useful hints in the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099369/interpolate-between-rotation-matrices ?

Comment: @Catree I don't know very much about Kalman filters, but reading the wikipedia entry it seems its intended to solve a different kind of problem than this.

Comment: @Alessandro I don't see anything useful.  Quaternions are useful for representing 3D rotations, but in the case of a homography relating a planar region as seen in two images, there is only a single 2D rotation involved.  I'm decomposing the transform into TRS + shear as they do here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612006/decomposing-an-affine-transformation and then separately interpolating each component.  They also discuss how to interpolate between 2 affine transforms, but I don't see how to extend that to interpolate between a Gaussian weighted average of affine transforms

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, I don't want to interpolate between the entire affine transform, I want to do something like a Gaussian convolution of just the TRS values, but leave shear/perspective unchanged because changing shear/perspective would introduce weird distortions.