# How to split transformation matrix into steps for animation?

Tags: python, numpy, animation

I have a 4D transformation matrix (rotation, translation and scale) that I can use to do [affine transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.affine_transform.html) of a 3D numpy array, from where I take a slice and display it. This part works and allows me to view rotated / moved / scaled 3D data.

However, when matrix changes, I would like to animate the transition. To do this I need to split my matrix `M` into steps such that `M` equals `S0 @ S1 @ S2 @ ... @ Sn`, where each step performs a tiny bit of rotation, translation and scale.

Alternatively, I could animate the transition by making e.g. rotation as a series of small rotations and the consume them one by one, but if there is another operation while the previous one is still in progress, I would like to merge them and go in the direction of the end state directly. So getting a series of steps would be preferable.

Is it possible to split my transformation matrix into such steps, and if yes, how?

Comment: This might be easier if you split this matrix into two pieces - one for rotation and one for scaling and translation. You can SLERP the rotation matrix and LERP the scaling/translation matrix. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099369/interpolate-between-rotation-matrices

Comment: This has the advantage that if you want to explicitly compute what the state should be 39.2% of the way through the animation, you can compute that, without having to compute all the intermediate states.

Comment: That would work - I decompose the matrix and apply SLERP/LERP to get the next step... Thank you, much appreciated! (if you post this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it)